# tsne removes cases in the process of dimension reduction

Tags: r

the dataframe COLS_SOURCE with 388 rows is put through tsne.
The resulting two dimension are then merged with COLS_SOURCE to reobtain the id of the rows.

On cbinding I get the message that the length (rows) of both dataframes are not the samen. How is this possible?

Tsne_with_ID = cbind.data.frame(COLS_SOURCE[,1],tsne_model_1$Y)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 388, 386

```
# I.2 TSNE (t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding)
set.seed(123)  
tsne_model_1 = Rtsne(COLS_SOURCE, check_duplicates=FALSE, pca=TRUE, perplexity=30, theta=0.5, dims=2)

Tsne_with_ID = cbind.data.frame(COLS_SOURCE[,1],tsne_model_1$Y)
```

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: Are there NA values in your original data? Two of them maybe?

Comment: G5W you are right.